# Make maven child depend on different version of library

Tags: java, maven

Both projects A and B depend on project C.

Project C depends on project D, specified as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>D</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

in project C's pom.xml

However, project B doesn't work with the project C that depends on D version 2.0

But A only works with project C depending on D version 2.0

Can I change something in project B's pom.xml to make it build C with D version 1.0?

Comment: Pretty sure you're not allowed to have multiple versions of the same library/project in the dependency tree due to namespace ambiguity.

Comment: I'm suggesting keeping project D's pom the same, but change B's - projects A and B would have different versions of the library D, but in *different* dependency trees

Comment: The JVM class loader loads the classes in certain order. Once it has loaded a class, it WILL NOT load the same namespace class again! Meaning any one version of class can remain in the JVM (as Powerlord already said). Even if you put 2 versions of jar files in same application, you might see weird/different behavior every time you restart the application. Better you fix your project to depend on one version otherwise you will just keep fixing the wrong thing all the times.

Comment: This is what maven versions are for. Let B depend on an old version of C which is built previously and installed in a repository.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. use `<exclusions>`. Good luck!
B's pom.xml

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>C</artifactId>
  <version>${C.version}</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>some.group</groupId>
      <artifactId>D</artifactId>
     </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>some.group</groupId>
  <artifactId>D</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: If both A and B are used in the same process, please comment. I'll show you how to avoid conflict using `shade`.